# Disable only Modern Team Site Creation but allow Modern Communication Site Creation

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-framework, modern-experience

I wanted to know, if we could disable the modern Team Site Creation button when +Create Site is clicked but at the same time allow users to create Modern Communication Sites from the +Create Site button from https://tenant URL/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx.

As from the URL you can see _layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx is an application page and making any changes would be really too difficult.
If there are any insights on how this can be done or any pointers for approach would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but requires you to set the property  `Use the form at this URL` and specifying a custom form that handles the site creation logic.Inside this custom form you could present only the option to create a communication site.

To access the setting open **SharePoint Admin Center -> Settings > Site Creation**

[Manage site creation in SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-creation?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-gb%252farticle%252fManage-site-creation-in-SharePoint-Online-e72844a3-0171-47c9-befb-e98b23e2dcf9)

Comment: Thanks for the info and going by what you suggest is correct if we want to define our own provisioning logic. But if I have Use the form at this URL, I am basically delegating my provisioning engine to a provider hosted app. However, if you see the Description/Detail of the option - it also says that "Users will be able to create sites that include group from other places in O365". If it is so, then we need to run PNPCmdlets to disable group creation. So in turn there are too many steps. From Admin point, there should be more control on site creation.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but this is the only real option available for us at this stage. If my answer was useful please upvote or mark as answer.